# Complex Analysis: Show that $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)}dz=\frac{2\pi i}{a-b}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, circles

How can I show that if $|a|<r<|b|$, then

$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)}dz=\frac{2\pi i}{a-b}$,

where $\gamma$ is the circle with center the origin, radius $r$, and positive orientation?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using Cauchy's Theorem?

Comment: Simple poles are nice and so is the residue theorem.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Residue Theorem?

Comment: Yes thank you, I took a look at the residue theorem and it works nicely.

Comment: Duplicated of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125717/complex-integral-over-a-circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use Cauchy's integral formula. It says that for any simple, closed curve $\gamma$, and any function $f(z)$ that is holomorphic on the open region $U \subseteq \Bbb C$ bounded by $\gamma$ (and continuous on the closed region $\overline U$ bounded by $\gamma$), then
$$
\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{(z-\xi)}dz = 2\pi if(\xi)
$$
for any $\xi\in U$.

In your case, you want to set $f(z) = \frac{1}{z-b}$, $\xi = a$ and let $\gamma$ be the circle centered at the origin with radius $r$. The formula you're asked to prove should pop out immediately.

Comment: Thank you so much! I hadn't thought of applying this theorem, but it's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the same approach using the Residue Theorem:
Since $|a|<r<|b|$, the curve $\gamma$ contains one pole, that is $a$. 
Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-b)(z-a)}$ 
So, we have: 
 $I=\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{(z-a)(z-
b)}dz$

Then, by applying the Residue theorem for $f$ in $γ$, we get: 
$I=2\pi{i} Res(f(z),a)=2\pi{i}(lim_{z\rightarrow a} (z-a)f(z))=$ $\frac{2\pi{i}}{a-b}$